# Problem using LibAo on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, audio

I'm trying to use LibAo on Windows 7. The ao_default_driver_id function returns -1 (it can't find any default sound output).
I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Does LibAo require something more to work?

```
ao_initialize();
int driver_id = ao_default_driver_id();
```

/Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using libao as well for a project.  To help you troubleshoot, did you build the library yourself or did you use a precompiled binary?